# Build GCC 4.8.1 or higher on CentOS 6.5

Tags: gcc, installation, rpm, centos6.5

I want to use GCC 4.8.1 or higher on a HPC machine with CentOS 6.5 which has a very old GCC. I do not have admin rights so everything has to be local. Do I have to really compile everything from source? Isn't there any rpm package that I can only install GCC with its dependencies? I found GCC rpms for CentOS 7 but not 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

Without admin rights, building from source is
likely most reliable means to use gcc-4.8.1.

You can try installing (or extracting) gcc-4.8.1
from the redhat developer tool kit 2.0 described here
     https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

CentOS 7 RPM's are unlikely to work in general on CentOS 6.x.
The developer 2.0 toolkit was built on CentOS6

Comment: Thank you. I had seen that link before but I couldn't make it work (perhaps I needed to spend more time). But, I found this other link (http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=1003) that someone made a script to build GCC from source with minimum efforts. It worked, but no gfortran included. That I have to do it myself, I guess.

Comment: I tried the script you mentioned, but it failed at one of the multilibs steps: `/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory`